# Magento 2: Order Summary expanded on page load?

Tags: magento2, sidebar, mini-cart

I've been trying to figure out how to have the Order Summary at the checkout page expanded on page load.

I attempted many approaches, all of which failed.

Comment: Please provide additional information where specifically you want something to happen. Also highlighting what approaches you tried so far will help in so far that no one will suggest you try the same.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

The full list of options for the collapsible widget can be seen on the dev docs [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_collapsible.html#fedg_collaps_active).

#### Finding the code

Navigate to `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html` and look at line 8 (on 2.1.1 at least), it should look like so:

```
<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active'}}">
```

#### Copy the file into your theme

As we don't want to edit the core we need to copy this file into your theme, so duplicate it and move it to:

```
app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/cart-items.html
```

#### Set the collapsible widget to be active when initialised

Now you can pass the active option (`'active': true`) to it. So the full line should be like so:

```
<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': true}}">
```

Now clear your caches, pub/static, and var/view_preprocessed. You should hopefully have an open cart summary when the widget is initialised.

Comment: It looks like you're missing some code. **So the full line should be like so:**

Comment: @Cam Your code isn't displaying :(

Comment: LOL. That's what I was trying to tell you about your answer. Anyway, it should look like this: `<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': true}}">`

Comment: I don't even have an excuse for that, I'm just stupid haha. I've sorted it now, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Should that be `app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/cart-items.html`? (note the added `summary`).

Comment: @BenCrook this worked for me, thanks. However, when I tried to set **display:block** to class .minicart-items (like this -> $('.checkout-index-index #opc-sidebar .opc-block-summary .items-in-cart .minicart-items').css('display', 'block');)  it worked only once. do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: I'd need to see the full code sorry, maybe create a new question?

Comment: @BenCrook  I am not sure hardcoding 'active': true is appropriate If you look at the file   the is `<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': isItemsBlockExpanded()}}">` the isItemsBlockExpanded(); comes from cart-item.js  `/**
         * Returns bool value for items block state (expanded or not)
         *
         * @returns {*|Boolean}
         */
        isItemsBlockExpanded: function () {
            return quote.isVirtual() || stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');
        }`    There must be a better way. !?

Comment: What version of Magento is that? On 2.1 it is set to `'active': true` in `cart-items.html`. Plus I never really use Magento's code as best practice as it rarely actually is the best practice.

Comment: If that is used in 2.2 I presume it's because `isItemsBlockExpanded` also takes into consideration what step the user is on, if you want it open at all times then you don't care what step the user is on. So removing that logic is a positive change as it's unnecessary logic in this case.

Comment: @BenCrook Ahh 2.2.2 I am!   Thank for the advise

Comment: I added another comment just above you btw explaining why I don't think it's such a bad thing to change it to true IF you want it open at all times. Providing it doesn't cause any issues anyway. I don't have a 2.2 environment to hand at the moment to test.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is Css:

```
// force minicart on checkout to be open
.minicart-items{display:block !important}
.product-item-details .content{display:block !important}
```

Comment: This is not a bad solution if you want it to be expanded always, not collapsible at all. I gave this a +1 for thinking outside the box and using all available options.

Comment: Awesome Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

in cart-items.js, I updated the return value for this function:

```
    isItemsBlockExpanded: function () {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go To Admin **Content->Configuration** and select your theme then edit.Under footer tab add this Css.You can either add it in css file. Thats it.

```
<style>
.content.minicart-items {
    display: block!important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Magento 2.3.x you can change your html template from:

`<div data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": true}}'>`

to:

`<div data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "active": true}}'>`

hope can help someone on new magento installation :)